# javascript bitwise xor producing inconsistent result

Tags: javascript, binary, bitwise-xor

I am using bitwise operations in javascript but I have noticed something that appears inconsistent.

Right now, I'm using the XOR (^) operation. When I do `'0101'^'0001'`, I get 4, which makes sense since 4 = 0100 in binary.
But when I do `'10001'^'01111'`, I get 9030, when I think I should get 11110.
The format is, to best that I can tell, the same; only the strings are different.

```
console.log(5^1); //4
console.log('0101'^'0001'); // 100 = 4

console.log(17^15); //30
console.log('10001'^'01111'); //9030...why? shouldn't it be '11110'?
```

Why is this code producing this result?

Now, If I do this:

```
console.log(('0b'+'10001')^('0b' + '01111')); //30
```

Why did I have to add `'0b'` to specify that the strings were binary sequences when doing bitwise ops on 17 and 15, but not with 5 and 1?

Comment: You are using strings... `'0101'^'0001'` results in `101^1` which happens to be `100`, **NOT** binary.

Comment: Oh I see. 101^1 is 0b1100101^0b0000001 = 0b1100100 = 100 in base 10

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `^` operator on strings. When using any numerical operator on a string JavaScript will implicitly convert the string to a number. Adding `0b` tells JavaScript to treat your number as a binary or base 2 number.

Otherwise, by default they will be converted to decimal or base 10 values.

Do operations on binary values represented in a string you have to convert your values to numerical base 2 values first.

You can verify in a calculator 10,001^1111 = 9030.

In binary 1111=15 and 10001=17. 15^17= 30 which is 11110‬ in binary.

101 Xor 1 is a special case, In decimal 101 Xor 1 = 100. In Binary 101 = 5 and  5 Xor 1 = 4 which is written out in binary as 100.

Comment: I see. As the comment by @ASDFGerte points out, that '0101'^'0001' produced 100 which I interpreted as 4 was coincidence, since the 100 it produced was 100 in base 10, or 0b1100100. I did not know that JS will convert strings to base 10.

Comment: When you use a numerical operator on a string JavaScript will convert that string to a number.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out already, you are not using binary numbers. Use the 0b prefix for binary numbers and toString(2) to convert back:

```
console.log((0b10001 ^ 0b01111).toString(2));
11110
```

The first example just works because 1 in decimal is the same as 1 in binary. The result is 100 (decimal) though, not 4. Javascript doesn't store the number format internally.